# How to connect-azaccount in Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

[image]

In the release pipeline, I am trying to connect to Azure AD by using Connect-Azaccount so I can run Get-AzADgroup to retrieve some Az AD group names and their guid and output to variables.

I created Azure Powershell task with the following inline script.

(Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName "group-name").origin

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as the answer(on the left of my reply, there is an option to mark), thanks.

Comment: Hi Joy, I haven't tried yet as I don't have permission to create AD application and Service Principal.  I will update you as soon as I get the permissions.

Comment: You can also use the existing AD application, if you create a devops project, it will automatically create an AD App named like `organizationname-projectname-513f22f1-befd-xxxxxxcfe90f` in the App Registerations in your tenant. But you also need the permission to `Grant admin consent for xxx`. May be you could ask your admin to grant the api permission for you.:-)

Comment: Hi Joy, i've created request to have our security team create the AD application. Still waiting..

Comment: Hi Joy, under Azure Subscription in AZ powershell task, are you using service principal or Managed Service Identity service connection?

Comment: I used the service principal.

Comment: Hi Joy, I'm getting an error while running the Azure PowerShell task.
could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version: ''.

Comment: I'm using task version 4.* (preview)

Comment: Hi Joy, do you know what the issue is here?

Comment: I am not sure, I recommend you to post a new question to ask the specific error.

Comment: Hi Joy, I was able to fix the error. do you know what kind of role you gave the SP?

Comment: It depends on your requirement, in my sample, I did not give a role to the SP, I just give the AAD Graph permission `Directory.Read.All`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need to use a non-interactive login, follow the steps as below.

1. [Create an Azure Active Directory application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application) and [create a secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret) for the app, save the secret and [get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-values-for-signing-in).
2. In your AD App -> `API permissions` -> `Add a permission` -> select `Azure Active Directory Graph` -> `Application permissions` -> `Directory.Read.All` -> click `Add permissions` -> click **`Grant admin consent for xxx`**, refer to the screenshot.

   [image]

   [image]
3. Try the script as below, use the values which you get in step 1,  it works fine on my side.

   **Note**: You need to use the `Task version` with `4.*(preview)` when you use `Az` powershell module.

   ```
   $azureAplicationId ="<your ad app application id>"
   $azureTenantId= "<your tenant id>"
   $azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<the secret of your ad app>" -AsPlainText -Force
   $psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
   Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal 
   #I just test to get all groups, you could do other operations
   Get-AzADGroup
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Joy Wang,
I have used as per your mention method but didn't login.
Check below error:
Connect-AzAccount : ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error 
message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See 
https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.