# How to implement Update-AzSqlServerVulnerabilityAssessmentSetting using AzureRM

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I have an Az script that sets up **Advanced Data Security** for my Azure SQL Databases/Servers.

Unfortunately, Az cannot run in Azure Devops, so I translated the script to AzureRM. The script leaves  **Advanced Data Security** in a "Partially Configured" state, due to the Azure SQL Server's VULNERABILITY ASSESSMENT SETTINGS not being set.

What is the AzureRM equivalent of **Update-AzSqlServerVulnerabilityAssessmentSetting**

I tried

```
Update-AzSqlServerVulnerabilityAssessmentSetting
```

to:

```
Update-AzureRmSqlDatabaseVulnerabilityAssessmentSettings
```

However, only the database gets configured and this leave the Server unconfigured.

Comment: There may not be an equivalent. AzureRM isn't getting updated anymore.

Answer (score 0):

They are not an equivalent, the `AzureRm` module was deprecated and will not be updated.

> Unfortunately, Az cannot run in Azure Devops, so I translated the script to AzureRM.

As I know, the `Task version` with `4.*(preview)` supports `Az` module. I tried it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350960/how-to-connect-azaccount-in-azure-devops-release-pipeline/56353214#56353214).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to AzureRm module to update Azure SQL Vulnerability Assessment Setting, you just can use command "update-AzureRmSqlDatabaseVulnerabilityAssessmentSettings" to configure all database in one server, AzureRM does not provide command to enable customers to directly configure Azure SQL server. For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2018/08/02/azure-sql-vulnerability-assessment-now-with-powershell-support/).

```
Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $params.rgname -ServerName $params.serverName`
        | where {$_.DatabaseName -ne "master"}  `
        | Update-AzureRmSqlDatabaseVulnerabilityAssessmentSettings `
            -RecurringScansInterval Weekly `
                 -NotificationEmail $scanNotificationEmail `
                 -EmailAdmins $true"
```