# Azure Automation Runbooks, Connect-AzAccount, Assigning rights

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-automation

I am trying to do some basic group management using Azure Automation, but I'm having a heck of a time getting the script to authenticate correctly.

I have added the Azure.Account modules to the runbook, and the connection seems to get established (at least, it doesn't throw an exception, and the returned object is not null).

When using "Get-AzAdGroup", I am getting:

```
Get-AzADGroup : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

The app account created is a "Contributor" in AAD, so as far as I understand, has full rights to the directory.

I have tried the solution listed at [How to connect-azaccount in Azure DevOps release pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350960/how-to-connect-azaccount-in-azure-devops-release-pipeline), to the same effect (Insufficient privileges).  I have also applied "Group.Read.All", "Group.ReadWrite.All", "GroupMember.Read.All", "GroupMember.ReadWrite.All" based on what I can read from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#group-permissions - but I'm not 100% clear if the Az* cmdlets use the Microsoft Graph, or if that's separate altogether.

Code is as follows:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    <#
    # Original, technically legacy. 
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
    #>

    $connectState = Connect-AzAccount `
       -ServicePrincipal `
       -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
       -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
       -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint


    <#
    # From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350960/how-to-connect-azaccount-in-azure-devops-release-pipeline, same result.
    $AzurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "*****" -AsPlainText -force
    $psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId , $AzurePassword)
    $connectState = Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId  -ServicePrincipal 
    #>

    if ($connectState) {
        "Connected."
    } else {
        "Doesn't seem to be connected."
    }
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

# Get groups
Get-AzADGroup
```

My gut tells me that since both connect-azaccount methods yield the same result (connected, but no access) my issue isn't necessarily in the script, but short of creating a service account (which presents challenges with MFA), I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Hi, could my reply solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

From the solution [How to connect-azaccount in Azure DevOps release pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56353214/9455659) I provided, in the screenshot, it is clear that you need to add the API permission of `Azure Active Directory Graph`, not `Microsoft Graph`.

Please add the `Directory.Read.All` in `Azure Active Directory Graph` for the AD App of your automation run as account.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be the minimum set of privileges required to run this Az PowerShell command.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a very similar issue. You have a problem with the API permissions Azure APP has.

In my case, my **azure App was working as a Service Principal**, and not only modifying some stuff in the **Azure AD**, but also some **Azure resources**, therefore, these were the api permissions that I had to grant:
[image]

> Remember that you also need to grant admin consent from the Azure tenant for these permissions update.

Answer (score 0):

If you just assign `Contributor` role to the service principal, you just can use the sp to get Azure resource(such as VM, app service). So if you want to use the sp tp get Azure AD resource, we need to assign Azure AD role (sucah as Directory Readers) to the sp. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles)

The detailed steps are as below

1. Get the RunAsAccount sp object id

[image]

[image]

2. Confugure Permisisons for the application

```
  connect-AzureAD

$sp=Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId <the sp object id your copy>

$role=Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object{$_.DisplayName -eq "Directory Readers"}
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId  -RefObjectId $sp.ObjectId
```

3. Test
   a. create a new runbook

   ```
      $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureRunAsConnection'
   $connectState = Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
   if ($connectState) {
         "Connected."
     } else {
         "Doesn't seem to be connected."
     }

   Get-AzADGroup
   ```

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

**Go to Azure portal --> Azure AD --> roles and Administrator-->Directory Readers role --> assign this role to the runbook account name**