# Connect-AzAccount with Azure Devops Pipeline?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am finding difficulties in finding the **best and secure** way to use connect-azaccount with azure devops pipeline. I have in the pipeline the following this simple powershell script which is used to create azure resources. Just to simplify things I only used the creation of a resource group:

```
$Location = "Location Name"
$resourceGroupName = "Resource Group Name"

try {

    #Creation of Resource Group
    $resourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

    if($null -eq $resourceGroup)
    {
        New-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $Location
    }

    else
    {
        Write-Host "The ResourceGroup with the name: $resourceGroupName already exists."
    }

} 


catch 
{
    Write-Host "Error occurred: $_"
}
```

The problem here is when the pipeline is being run and it reaches the Powershell task, it gives me an error, **Error occurred: Run Connect-AzAccount to login.**

My issue here is that I honestly don't know which way is the most secure way to connect without typing any user credentials. It should directly connect and create the resources. **Note that I am using Multi-Factor Authentication**. In order to achieve that I found several solutions but I need help in choosing the best way. I found several solutions by adding a powershell task in the Yaml file. Here is the Yaml showing the powershell task to run the script:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/Deploy/functionapp.ps1'
```

Option 1:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' -SubscriptionId 'yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy'
```

Now the problem here is that the Tenant ID and Subscription are going to be visible in the code and that is a very bad practice

Option 2 is to use the following script:

```
$User = "xxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<Password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenant = "<tenant id>"
$subscription = "<subscription id>"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User,$PWord
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenant -Subscription $subscription
```

This is very similar to the first, but if I am not mistaken it is limited to a specific user.

Option 3 is to use a service principal:

```
$azureAplicationId ="Azure AD Application Id"
$azureTenantId= "Your Tenant Id"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "strong password" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal
```

I don't know if creating a service principal will incur any costs and what steps should I do to make it work.

I am honestly new to all this, can someone please provide me what are the exact steps to achieve this. Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Neither of these 3 options are suitable since they all require you to store the plaintext password in the script. [Use a service principal instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350960/how-to-connect-azaccount-in-azure-devops-release-pipeline) (and store your subscription IDs as secrets if you don't want to store them in the script)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you very much for your answer. So it is basically option 3 but adding to it is to store the  subscription ID as secret. But my question here is how can I access this value in the script ? Is there a way to get that value ? In that case, what should change in the script above in option 3 ?

Comment: Depends on where you store the secret. If using [AKV: `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell). If storing as secret variables within the pipeline, use [variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables), eg. `"$(name.of.secret)"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most secure way is to [create an Azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops) and use it in your pipeline. You can create it using automated way, or manually using previously created service principal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But does this service connection incur any additional costs ?

Comment: It's free. Behind the scenes it uses app registration (free), it gets assigned contributor role on subscription or resource group level.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll have a look at it. But do you have an idea if I should anything in the Yaml file or powershell script to access this connection. So in this case if I use the service connection I should no longer use Connect-AzAccount because the connection is already established right  ?

Comment: You don't have to use Connect-AzAccount. Use parameter azureSubscription and specify there your service connection name. Like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/media/yaml-connection-setting.png

Comment: Please find a full guide there :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: I will try it. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You are welcome, happy new year! ☺️

Comment: @KamilKonderak I think it's worth emphasising in your answer that the [AzurePowershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell) should be used in the pipeline, not the [Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell).

Comment: Good point @VinceBowdren!

Comment: @Vince Bowdren Where should the AzurePowerShell Task be used ? I think instead of the Task mentioned in the image you provided Task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment I should use Task: AzurePowerShell@5 and add the azuresubscrption: "ARM Connection Name" and add the filepath of the script that I want to run right ?

Comment: Hi @Noobie2021; I think that would be a separate question. Why don't you have a go with the service connection, using the azure powershell task according to the docs, and come back with a new question if you have any specific problems with it?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I think that was part of the question. As you can see in the Yaml file provided in my question. I am trying to run the script but first I need to make sure that the connection is made through the Arm Service Connection you mentioned. So since you highlighed the point of using the AzurePowerShell Task. I thought maybe it would be an idea to use it instead of what I used above in the Yaml file and add the azuresubscription based on ARM connection I established

Comment: @Noobie2021 please try out what has already been suggested. This is not a site for general tutorials which will guide you through everything you need to do step by step; it is a site for specific questions and specific answers, helping people who have already made a good-faith effort to solve the problem for themselves.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Thank you so much for your help. Everything you told me worked like a charm. I also tested what I mentioned in the last comment it also worked :)